# Размерность пересечения плоскостей в многомерном пространстве

Tags: математика, геометрия

У меня есть пространство R<sup>n</sup> и две поверхности в нём, размерностей `m` и `k`.

Чему равна размерность пересечения этих поверхностей?

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что вопросы по математике являются оффтопиком для сайта so.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Подразумевая, что в вопросе, под «поверхностями» подразумеваются подпространство. Размерность пересечения будет не меньше (k+m-n) и, очевидно, не больше min (m,k).

Строго доказать не смогу, но рассуждать можно так:

1. Поверхность размерности k в пространстве n описывается (n-k) линейно независимыми уравнениями.
2. Пересечение k-  и m- мерных поверхностей описывается системой из (n-k)+(n-m) уравнений.
3. Если все уравнения в (2) также ЛНЗ, то получаем (n-k)+(n-m)=n-(k+m-n) уравнений, т.е. эта система задаёт подпространство размерности k+m-n.